# Generate randomNumber in server every X seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

### Background

I am making a Node.js app that generates a random number every 6 seconds, and makes it available via an API.

To keep the number generation logic out of the API file, I encapsulated in a function called `numberGen`, in another file.

**api.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const numberFactory = require("../numberGen.js");

module.exports = (function() {
    let interval = 6, min = 0, max = 100;

    const api = express.Router();
    const numberGen = numberFactory({
        interval, min, max
    });
    numberGen.run();

    api.get("/Numbers/", (req, res) => {
        res.json({ random: numberGen.currNum});       
    });

    return api;
})();
```

**numberGen.js**

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(args) {
    let {
        interval,
        min,
        max
    } = args;

    let currNumber = genRandom(min, max);

    function run() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            currNumber = genRandom(min, max);
            run();
        }, interval);
    }

    function genRandom(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    }

    return {
        interval, currNumber,
        run
    };
};
```

Ideally, a client make a request at 0 seconds, would get number X, and making the same request 6 seconds after, would get a number Y, as the server generates a new random number every 6 seconds.

### Problem

The problem here is that the client always gets the same number, no matter what.

### Tentatives

At first I thought this was happening because `numberGen` is returning an object that never changes. To fix it, I tried passing a number from the `api.js` to the generator to update, but it didn't work either as the client always gets an empty object, because `serverNum === undefined`;

**numberGen.js**

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(args) {
    let {
        interval,
        min,
        max,
        serverNum
    } = args;

    serverNum = genRandom(min, max);

    function run() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            serverNum= genRandom(min, max);
            run();
        }, interval);
    }

    function genRandom(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    }

    return {
        interval,
        run
    };
};
```

**api.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const numberFactory = require("../numberGen.js");

module.exports = (function() {
    let interval = 6, min = 0, max = 100, serverNum;

    const api = express.Router();
    const numberGen = numberFactory({
        interval, min, max, serverNum
    });
    numberGen.run();

    api.get("/Numbers/", (req, res) => {
        res.json({ random: serverNum});       
    });

    return api;
})();
```

### Question

Having in mind I want to keep this logic separated from the `api.js` file, how can I fix my code?

Comment: setInterval instead of setTimeout ?

Comment: At this point, using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is completely irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: You need to make the RNG global and initialize only once, otherwise you'll get the same numbers.

Comment: @Robert: That's not the problem.

Comment: You are accessing `currNum` instead of `currNumber`. Also, in `setTimeout`, you need interval as `interval * 1000` if you want 6 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object you're returning contains the value of `currNumber` at that specific point in time - not a reference. Add a function that returns the actual current value of the number and call that instead of `numberGen.currNum`.

**numberGen.js**

```
module.exports = function(args) {
  // add this function
  function getNumber() {
    return currNumber;
  }
}
```

**api.js**

```
api.get("/Numbers/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ random: numberGen.getNumber()});       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simplify your code to
**api.js**

```
const express = require("express");


module.exports = (function() {
let interval = 6, min = 0, max = 100, serverNum;

const api = express.Router();
function genRandom(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

setInterval(function () {
    serverNum=genRandom(min,max)
    console.log(serverNum);
}, 6000);

api.get("/Numbers/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ random: serverNum});
});

return api;
})();
```